# Initialize a List<?> in a JUnit via @Rule

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit-rule

I am writing a JUnit test case. I want to initialize a list objects. For brevity, let's initialize a list of `String` objects:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Rule
    public List<MySQLContainer> tests = Arrays.asList(new MySQLContainer("5.5"), new MySQLContainer("5.6"));

    @Test
    public void myTest() {

    }
}
```

When executing, I get the following runtime error:

```
org.junit.internal.runners.rules.ValidationError: The @Rule 'tests' must implement MethodRule or TestRule.
at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleMemberValidator$FieldMustBeARule.validate(RuleMemberValidator.java:234)
at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleMemberValidator.validateMember(RuleMemberValidator.java:99)
at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleMemberValidator.validate(RuleMemberValidator.java:93)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateFields(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:196)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:1
```

I don't get such error when I simply initialize a `MySQLContainer` instead of `List<MySQLContainer>`.

Why is this not working? How can I fix it?

I have JUnit 4.12 in my dependencies.

Comment: Why do you even need the `@Rule` annotation there? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In my situation, I am initializing `MySQLContainer` instances from TestContainers project. I'll edit my post.

Comment: this still looks like a constant list. Why do you need a `@Rule` there?

Comment: I want the functionality behind `@Rule`. I want the MySQL containers to initialize before each test. I understood that was the goal of `@Rule`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`@Rule`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Rule.html)s are for executing code before each test method. If you just need to initialize a member, put this initialization in a method annotated with [`@Before`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Before.html):

```
public class MyTest {    
    private List<MySQLContainer> containers;

    @Before
    public void initContainers() {
        containers =  = Arrays.asList(new MySQLContainer("5.5"), new MySQLContainer("5.6"));
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        // Some test...    
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `@Before` was a good idea. I am now using `@Before` and calling `.start()` on each container.

Comment: And `@After` which calls `.stop()` on each container.

Comment: You don't have to use `@Before`. Just remove the `@Rule` and everything is fine.

Comment: @StefanBirkner There is no contract regarding when a test class is instantiated. If you initialize a member in the test class' constructor (or inline, which implicitly just means it's initialized thus in every constructor), you may get the same instance between tests. Sometimes this is OK (e.g., if it's static/constant data), but sometimes test X may modify this data and create unexpected behavior in test Y. OP didn't provide enough context to discern if this is the case or not, but generally speaking it's a bad practice, and should be avoided unless you have a **very** good reason to do so.

Comment: There's an implicit contract for the default JUnit runner. It creates a new instance of the test class for each test. Therefore you don't need `@Before`. Other runners may reuse test instances but that is very uncommon. See also https://martinfowler.com/bliki/JunitNewInstance.html

Answer (score 2):

Try using ArrayList()

```
    public List<MySQLContainer> tests = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@Rule` and everything is fine.

```
public class MyTest {

    private final List<MySQLContainer> tests = Arrays.asList(
        new MySQLContainer("5.5"),
        new MySQLContainer("5.6")
    );

    @Test
    public void myTest() {

    }
}
```

`@Rule` is used for JUnit 4 extensions and make it possible to do some more complex things.